# How to make status bar color changeable in Ionic 2

Tags: colors, ionic2, header, statusbar

I saw a lot of applications developed by ionic 2 that support status bar color with same color of header but I couldn't did that in my application

This image shows my status bar when I built it as apk and installed on my android phone

[image]

But I want to do such as this (if possible)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refer to this documentation:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar/

To change color you can try on your **app.component.ts**, inside your *constructor* there:

(Assuming you have injected `statusBar: StatusBar` on your ctor)

```
this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ffffff');
```

Not sure on how to decrease a bit of it's opacity like the example you have shown. Perhaps:

```
this.statusBar.styleBlackOpaque()
//or
this.statusBar.styleBlackTranslucent()
```

Let us know what worked for you.

Comment: what hex value did you use for your case / for the example above?

Comment: you can use your header hex color but try to make it more darker

Comment: Didn't you need it to be a bit transparent?

Comment: I checked the other 2 codes but nothing happens 

this.statusBar.styleBlackOpaque() //or this.statusBar.styleBlackTranslucent()

Comment: What if i want to change the background color to white and icons to black.I changed the background color to white, but icons are still the white. Could u please help me?

Comment: `this.statusBar.styleBlackTranslucent()`
this code makes the statusbar text look white, so it requires to make it look as shown in image above, along with the `BackgroundColorByHexString`

Answer (score 2):

**Your answer with Code**

```
//set top status bar overlay
statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
// set status bar to red
statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#f00');
```

Visit this site to  a Link and Learn More tutorials with code

**Get Full code**

http://www.jawabadda.com/pages/technical-guru/how-to-change-color-top-status-bar-in-ionic/